# Permanently Disable Dell Latitude 2120 Touchscreen in X.org Upon Start-up and Suspend/Restore

Tags: linux, xorg, login, touchscreen

In the spirit of full disclosure, below is the background, **tl;dr:** I am running Lubuntu Oneiric and I want to disable my borked touchscreen, running it on X.org start-up works but suspending the system and waking it up resets the settings and enables the touchscreen again. How can I make sure that it is not enabled again upon login? And what is it that causes the settings to be restored?

I have a Dell Latitude 2120 with the touch screen option. Unfortunately it is either broken in hardware or software (I suspect hardware since it worked perfectly for about a month after I received it) and at random intervals clicks in a specific region of the screen. Sometimes the click registered is instant, sometimes it is detected as the right key being held down. I contacted Dell but since they won't replace the screen for anything other than yet anther touchscreen I went with the option of disabling it in software using `xinput` as follows (I got the device details using `xinput list`):

```
xinput set-prop 'IDEACOM  IDC 6651' 'Device Enabled' 0
```

Running this on system start-up was a piece of cake using a simple shell script and adding it to the start-up programs list for the window manager and it worked just fine when running Ubuntu Lucid. My guess is that there has been a change in behaviour to comply with the Freedesktop standardisation. Does anyone have any idea on how to disable a touchscreen idiomatically and what is causing the device settings to be restored after a suspend/restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added hid_multitouch to the modprobe blacklist...

```
echo "blacklist hid_multitouch" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```